# How to change indentation rules in SublimeText3?

Tags: ide, sublimetext3, auto-indent

In my company, we are all working on Sublime and my boss want us to have a specific indentation for js and php files. He wants us to indent the closing curly braces at the same indentation as the code above. (If found that it's named [Ratliff style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Ratliff_style)) Here is an example.

```
function resetScraperSubmit() {
    var button = $('.modal#scrapperConfiguration').find('button[type=submit]');
    button.text(button.data('default-text'))
        .addClass('btn-primary')
        .removeClass('btn-danger')
        .prop('disabled', false);
    }
```

To do this, I have to indent myself all of them all the time.

Is there any feature/configuration file in Sublime or in one of his plugin to automatically do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can customise you sublime indentation settings from the settings tab

```
Preferences ->  Settings
```

Copy the rules that you want to customise from the default settings window wich most if the time appears at the left side and paste it to the right hand side  and change the value

```
"detect_indentation": true,
"auto_indent": true,
"auto_indent": true, 
"indent_to_bracket": false,
```

And so on 
Here is the [Sublime Indentation Manual](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/indentation) Read it and follow the rules